# I am trying to make a simple calculator using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

```
def add(a,b):
    print (a+b)
def sub(a,b):
    print (a-b)
def mult(a,b):
    print (a*b)
def div(a,b):
    print(a/b)



while True:    
    print("1. + \n2. -\n3. * \n4. / \n5. Exit")
    a=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
   
    
    if a==5:
        print("Thank you for using My c@|cu|@t0r")
        break
    else:
        no1=int(input("Enter first no: "))
        no2=int(input("Enter second no: "))
        calc={
                    1:add(no1,no2),
                    2:sub(no1,no2),
                    3:mult(no1,no2),
                    4:div(no1,no2),
                    5:exit()
                }
        calc[a] 
        continue
```

I have used this code to make a simple calculator, but the output I got is not what I expected. This is the output I am getting :

```
1. + 
2. -
3. * 
4. / 
5. Exit
Enter your choice: 1
Enter first no: 3
Enter second no: 2
5
1
6
1.5
```

It's running all the functions, where I just want one output

Answer (score 2):

The functions `add(a,b)` etc. are executed when you construct the dictionary (`calc={add(no1,no2), ...`), not when you access its element (`calc[a]`). Because of this, the results of all operations are printed each time.

One option could be to define the dictionary as dictionary of functions (rather than result values), while calling the function of interest *after* selecting it from the dictionary:

```
        calc={
                    1:add,
                    2:sub,
                    3:mult,
                    4:div
                }
        calc[a](no1,no2)
```

Note that you don't need the entry `5:exit()`, since that is handled before the `else` block.

Also, in this case you don't need to define the `calc` dictionary inside the loop (can be placed before the `while`).

Comment: Also worth mentioning that there's no need to write the add, sub, mult, div functions as they're all available in the *operator* module as add, sub, mul and truediv respectively

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up my doubt, but is there any option for switch case in python? It would be great if you could recommend something.